# Pie of a Pie chart in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a question regarding to Highcharts option for plotting a "pie-of-a-pie" chart. I need to show something similar to the one: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-of-a-pie/?theme=material Can i do the same thing in Highcharts? If yes please do help.

If not possible in High Charts, can you please help in amcharts only?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that result in Highcharts. You can use two `pie` series and update one of them in `series.point.events.click` funtion. For example:

```
series: [{
  data: [{
    y: 1,
    details: [1, 3, 2]
  }, {
    y: 2,
    details: [4, 31, 2]
  }, {
    y: 3,
    details: [14, 3, 2]
  }],
  point: {
    events: {
      click: function() {
        var series = this.series.chart.series;

        series[1].setData(this.details.slice());
      }
    }
  },
  center: [200, 100],
  size: 200
}, {
  size: 100,
  center: [500, 100],
  data: []
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4996/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.size

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.center

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.point.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData